# Office-js outlook - Open Task pane only when composing new email

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am creating a javascript based outlook task pane (sideload) for email compose. I am able to open task pane for email compose already. Now, I wanted to refine the rule more to open task pane only for new fresh email and not for reply emails. Is this possible? I could not find in document but if there is any way to achieve this.

I am currently using

```
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
     <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
</Rule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't support it currently. If you need this feature and wish to file a request, please use the link: https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions. And, may I know the use case of the add-in so that we can help better?

Comment: From our web app, we are going to open an outlook email with list of email addresses in the bcc. Outlook add-in will read the emails and on send, we will do some operations in our database.
This should only happen in new email case and not in reply.

Comment: As suggested, please open a request at:  https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions for your first requirement. For the second one since you have already opened a new post, you can delete it from here.